# I've suddenly lost my voice (aphonia) due to illness (laryngitis?) -- how to get it back fast?! Speaking to a 1,000 ppl in 2 days. Eeek

Tags: treatment-options, sore-throat, glossophobia, laryngitis

I'm presenting at the most important academic conference of my entire career thus far in 2 days (presenting research to literally 900-1000 people), and as luck would have it **my voice has suddenly disappeared (aphonia** -- albeit temporary). I haven't been straining it in anyway, but I have been experiencing a **sore-throat and fatigue and a tickling in my throat** and now it's completely gone.... (not sure if it's laryngitis). Unfortunately, I'm boarding an international flight in less than 15 hours and don't have time to see a doctor, **what are my treatment options?**

I already suffer from major **glossophobia (fear of public speaking)** so this is quite possibly the worst thing to lump on top of me. Ah! *(Is it possible I lost my voice out of fear?).*

Anyway, any tips on how to regain a voice would be very much appreciated!!